# How to work around 100K character limit for the StanfordNLP server?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to parse book-length blocks of text with StanfordNLP. The http requests work great, but there is a non-configurable 100KB limit to the text length, MAX_CHAR_LENGTH in StanfordCoreNLPServer.java.

For now, I am chopping up the text before I send it to the server, but even if I try to split between sentences and paragraphs, there is some useful coreference information that gets lost between these chunks. Presumably, I could parse chunks with large overlap and link them together, but that seems (1) inelegant and (2) like quite a bit of maintenance.

Is there a better way to configure the server or the requests to either remove the manual chunking or preserve the information across chunks?

BTW, I am POSTing using the python requests module, but I doubt that makes a difference unless a corenlp python wrapper deals with this problem somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to start the server with the flag `-maxCharLength -1` and that'll get rid of the sentence length limit. Note that this is inadvisable in production: arbitrarily large documents can consume arbitrarily large amounts of memory (and time), especially with things like coref.

The list of options to the server should be accessible by calling the server with `-help`, and are [documented in code here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/76f2bcdcde0d2266e7ab50ebb95a629c407f5922/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLPServer.java#L84).

Comment: Ah, I see the commit, from August. I'm using a version from just before that. I'll update, then. Thanks!

Comment: Is it not in 3.8.0? I do know it's relatively new (i.e., certainly not in the first version of the server), but hopefully at least still in a recent release.

Comment: No, the 3.8.0 src still has the static MAX_CHAR_LENGTH.

Comment: Suboptimal. Well, it'll be in the next version, or else you can build the jar manually with `ant jar` from the root of the GitHub project.

Comment: There is some documentation for building the latest version here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

Comment: -1 did not work for me.  It complained something about true or something.  However, I was able to raise the value above 100000 to a value which worked better for me.  This is with Stanford 3.9

Comment: The MAX_CHAR_LENGTH is still static! Your answer is wrong

Comment: Can you share how to do it in python while using an IDE?