# Unable to run Stanford Core NLP annotator over whole data set

Tags: python, typeerror, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, keyerror

I have been trying to use Stanford Core NLP over a data set but it stops at certain indexes which I am unable to find. 
The data set is available on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/PromptCloudHQ/amazon-reviews-unlocked-mobile-phones/data

This is a function that outputs the sentiment of a paragraph by taking the mean sentiment value of individual sentences.

```html
import json
def funcSENT(paragraph):
    
    
    all_scores = []
    
    output = nlp.annotate(paragraph, properties={
        "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,parse,sentiment",
        "outputFormat": "json",
        # Only split the sentence at End Of Line. We assume that this method only takes in one single sentence.
        #"ssplit.eolonly": "true",
        # Setting enforceRequirements to skip some annotators and make the process faster
        "enforceRequirements": "false"
    })
    
    
    all_scores = []
    for i in range(0,len(output['sentences'])):
        all_scores.append((int(json.loads(output['sentences'][i]['sentimentValue']))+1))
        

    final_score = sum(all_scores)/len(all_scores)
    
    return round(final_score)
```

Now I run this code for every review in the 'Reviews' column using this code.

```html
import pandas as pd
data_file = 'C:\\Users\\SONY\\Downloads\\Amazon_Unlocked_Mobile.csv'
data = pd.read_csv( data_file)

from pandas import *
i = 0
my_reviews = data['Reviews'].tolist()
senti = []
while(i<data.shape[0]):
    senti.append(funcSENT(my_reviews[i]))
    i=i+1
```

But somehow I get this error and I am not able to find the problem. Its been many hours now, kindly help.

```
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFbCl.jpg
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you're using pycorenlp with nlp=StanfordCoreNLP(...) and a running StanfordCoreNLP server. I won't check the data you are using since it appears to require a Kaggle account.

Running with the same setup but different paragraph shows that printing "output" alone shows an error from the java server, in my case:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input word not tagged
```

I THINK that because there is no part-of-speech annotator, the server cannot perform the parsing. Whenever you use parse or depparse, I think you need to have the "pos" annotator as well.

I am not sure what the sentiment annotator needs, but you may need other annotators such as "lemma" to get good sentiment results.

Print output by itself. If you get the same java error, try adding the "pos" annotator to see if you get the expected json. Otherwise, try to give a simpler example, using your own small dataset maybe, and comment or adjust your question.

Comment: Tried adding 'pos' annotator but still getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error. It runs up til some index but then gives this error.

Comment: If you print(output) after calculating it, what does it say?

Comment: According to the code, I use the output['Sentiment'][i]['sentimentValue']
But if you are asking for individual iteration, then printing output for each iteration prints a dictionary of info for each sentence.

Comment: OK, so it is giving a valid 'output' after calculation? I thought the server was erroring out, as I could reproduce the error that way. That could give more debugging info, if the server output says anything.

Comment: The server displays java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Comment: Otherwise, print output['sentences'][i] before output[][]['sentimentValue'], see if you can find the sentence dictionary that is producing the actual error.

Comment: Ah. I ran into a problem where I could not upload more than 100K characters to a single annotate call before it refused to process. Let me find the question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678204/how-to-work-around-100k-character-limit-for-the-stanfordnlp-server/46678484?noredirect=1#comment80305482_46678484

Comment: Not sure if that produced a TimeoutException, but it might have. How much data is in the csv? If you only upload half of it, does it work? Try that sort of debugging.

Comment: The data is huge. 400,000 rows, each having a rating and review.

Comment: That much data would certainly throw the timeout exception, but I don't know why a bunch of separate calls to nlp.annotate would batch, so maybe not. From here, figure out which review causes the timeout, print it just before the call to nlp.annotate. Add more debugging info to the question.