# Stanford NLP Dedicated Server Max Character Limit

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to create a keyword extractor that goes through some documents at work and grabs all the main keywords. For the majority of my documents, it works great as they are emails or small documents, but I am starting to get a lot of documents that are timing out.

To fix the timing out, I thought that I could just use the sentence splitting annotator to build a list of sentences and then send a comfortable amount of sentences at a time. The only problem with this idea is that the server is telling me that it can only take 100000 characters.

I am using the Server API. How can I go about updating the server to take more characters or only grabbing up to 100000 characters of a string without losing any of the information or integrity of a sentence (e.g. not cutting off half a sentence at the end)?

NOTE: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678204/how-to-work-around-100k-character-limit-for-the-stanfordnlp-server) (How to work around 100K character limit for the StanfordNLP server?
) does not work for me. I believe it relates to an older version. Either way, I have tried to add `-maxCharLength -1` to my start script and it doesn't do anything.

My start script currently is

`java -mx8g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 36000 -quiet true
pause`

Comment: Which version of Stanford CoreNLP are you using?  Setting the maxCharLength to -1 should work.

Comment: You might try setting maxCharLength to 1000000 (any really big number)...it's possible the -1 is causing a problem with the argument parsing.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp A little embarrassing story: I downloaded the 3.7.0 version about a month ago somehow. Not sure why I didn't get the latest 3.9 version. I downloaded the latest version today and the maxCharLength now works, but yes, it doesn't like the -1 value. I set it rather high and it all seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should definitely work if you just set maxCharLength to a very large number and are using Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.2.  I tested this out and tokenized a document with 220000 characters for instance.  I think the "-1" is causing issues when running at the command line.